# Installing nodejs via puppet fails

Tags: node.js, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Basically I want to do the following using puppet:

```
1.sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
setup nodejs evironment(latest stable version) on puppet agent
2.sudo yum install git-(install git)
3.git clone git@gitlab.ishwarya.net:hello-world/nodejs-helloworld.git -(git clone the application repo)
4.Run the application
npm install
npm start
npm test
```

I am new to puppet configurtion management tool. So far,I have done puppet master -agent setup.

```
sudo yum install puppet-server on puppet master node
sudo yum install puppet on agent node
```

and was able to successfully install apache on my agent.

I am using puppet version 3.8.7 on RHEL. As a first step I need to install nodejs on puppet agent to run my application.

Installed the puppetlabs-nodejs module

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-nodejs
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp on master node contains below code:

```
class { '::nodejs':
  nodejs_dev_package_ensure => 'present',
  npm_package_ensure        => 'present',
  repo_class                => '::epel',
}
```

when i run the below command on agent i get this error:

```
puppet agent -t
```

the code fails with below error

```
 Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: 
Invalid resource type gpg_key at /etc/puppet/modules/nodejs/manifests/repo/nodesource/yum.pp:58 on node ip-**********
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: have you tried putting the version in single quotes? like `'6.2.2'`?

Comment: thanks for your comment. after adding quotes its says "Could not find class nodejs"  - i have edited my question.

Comment: Are you doing Puppet with or without a master? Is a class `nodejs` defined in your directory environment or modulepath? We can help with some more information.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i have edited  my question. please find it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either install the puppetlabs-nodejs module or write it yourself. Either way you should have a nodejs module which has the nodejs class defined in it's init.pp file.

Make sure the something like `include 'nodejs'` is called withing your manifest

Comment: i have installed the puppetlabs-nodejs module and changed my site.pp file. please check my question for more details. this time it fails with different error 'Invalid resource type gpg_key at /etc/puppet/modules/nodejs/manifests/repo/nodesource/yum.pp'

Comment: This 'answer' needs to be either updated or deleted. As it is, it merely suggests doing something the asker already stated he did in the question.

Comment: The question has been updated multiple times and the answer covers the issues others might experience as well

Answer (score 0):

installing the below  modules solved the error and installed nodejs

```
puppet module install treydock-gpg_key

puppet module install stahnma-epel
```